# JPA shared cache / second level cache in WildFly

Tags: hibernate, jpa, wildfly, second-level-cache, shared-cache

I'm using WildFly 8.1 so JPA 2.1 and Hibernate 4.3.5

I want to use JPA shared cache / second level cache in WildFly

I follow the WildFly documentation: https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/JPA+Reference+Guide#JPAReferenceGuide-UsingtheInfinispansecondlevelcache

here is my persitience.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="myAppPU" transaction-type="JTA">
    <jta-data-source>java:/jdbc/myAppDS</jta-data-source>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <shared-cache-mode>ENABLE_SELECTIVE</shared-cache-mode>
    <properties>
      <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
      <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>
      <property name="org.hibernate.flushMode" value="MANUAL"/>
      <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache" value="true"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

I set the property hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache to true
and set the shared-cache-mode to ENABLE_SELECTIVE

And entities (@Entity) I want to cached are annotated with @Cacheable(true), like that:

```
@Entity
@Cacheable(true)
public class Tooltip implements Serializable {
  @Id
  private String path ;
  private String description ;
  private Boolean rendered ;
  //...
}
```

But each time I visit a web page hibernate generate a lot of select to get all entities I have indicate as @Cacheable(true) even if I already visit the page (in the same session).

So it seems that the shared cache / second level cache is not working

Did I miss something?

---

Thank you hwellmann

I tried to put hibernate.cache.use_query_cache to true in the persitence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="myAppPU" transaction-type="JTA">
    <jta-data-source>java:/jdbc/myAppDS</jta-data-source>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <shared-cache-mode>ENABLE_SELECTIVE</shared-cache-mode>
    <properties>
      <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
      <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>
      <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache" value="true"/>
      <property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache" value="true" />
      <property name="org.hibernate.flushMode" value="MANUAL"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

and and the hint in the query I'm using

```
@Entity
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "FieldInfos.findAll", query = "SELECT i FROM FieldInfos i", hints = {@QueryHint(name="org.hibernate.cacheable",value="true")}),
    @NamedQuery(name = "FieldInfos.findByPath", query = "SELECT i FROM FieldInfos i WHERE i.path = :path", hints = {@QueryHint(name="org.hibernate.cacheable",value="true")})
})
@Cacheable(true)
public class FieldInfos implements Serializable {
    //...
}
```

but the problem remain

I also try with the new version of WildFly: 8.2 so Hibernate 4.3.7 but the problem remain too

Comment: Have you solved your problem?

Comment: Did you enable statistics & checked WildFly management console > Runtime > JPA tab?

Answer (score 2):

The second level cache only affects direct entity lookups, corresponding to `EntityManager.find()`.

If you're trying to avoid all sorts of `SELECT` queries affecting your cached entities, you also need to enable the query cache:

```
    <property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache" value="true" />
```

and you need to set a query hint `org.hibernate.cacheable=true` for each query to be cached.

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunatly it didn't works for me, I edit my post to explain

Comment: Setting cacheable in the query is important, maybe you can show the client code to see if you're doing it right? Alternatively, enable TRACE logging for `org.hibernate` and maybe even `org.infinispan` to see what's going exactly. Stepping through the code with a remote debugger would also help.