# JPA second level cache in wildfly8.2, hibernate-entitymanager 4.3.8.Final

Tags: java, hibernate, caching, jpa

I am trying to use second level cache in wildfly8.2
I am setting the properties via JavaConfig
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", hibernateHbm2ddlAuto);
    properties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", hibernateDialect);
    properties.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", "true");
    properties.setProperty("hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache", "true");
    properties.setProperty("hibernate.cache.use_query_cache" , "true");

but I get the following error

- Caused by: org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheRegionFactoryAvailableException: Second-level cache is used in the application, but property hibernate.cache.region.factory_class is not given; please either disable second level cache or set correct region factory using the hibernate.cache.region.factory_class setting and make sure the second level cache provider (hibernate-infinispan, e.g.) is available on the classpath.

Why is it giving that error as per documentation it is not required. Any input would be helpful.

[JPA shared cache / second level cache in WildFly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28065897/jpa-shared-cache-second-level-cache-in-wildfly)

Thanks
Sanjeev.

Answer (score 1):

You need to define the property hibernate.cache.region.factory_class, something like:

```
Configuration.setProperty("hibernate.cache.region.factory_class", "net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheRegionFactory")
```

I would use C3P0 or Infinispam as second level cache.

Comment: I don't think that has to be done. As per Jboss Wildfly docu. no need to set it. Enabling JPA second level cache should be enough. But this not working for me.                                                                                                                                            [link](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/JPA+Reference+Guide)

Comment: If you look at the link that you post, you will find the same configuration that I posted above: <property name="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class" value="org.jboss.as.jpa.hibernate4.infinispan.InfinispanRegionFactory"/>

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had unneeded persistence.xml file in subproject that was making wildfly wild - it was overriding configuration file.

Property `<entry key="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class" value="org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory"/>` was completely ignored. After removing(renaming) persistence.xml, wildfly would start again correctly with properties from database.xml. Hope it saves you some time
(Wildfly 9.0.1Final, Hibernate 4.3.6.Final)